# Pass data from Nginx to Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra

So we do have our Jekyll app that serves a static webpage, which includes a contact form.
This contact form request then gets passed (POST) to our Sinatra-app at http://sub.example.com/send_email to deliver an email to inform us about the new contact..

So far so good, everything works fine if we run the Sinatra-app by using

`bundle exec rackup config.ru`

However, upon starting nginx and passenger_ruby, our Sinatra app does not receive any data whatsoever.

We have set up the server like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.example.com;
    error_log /home/example/error.log warn;
    access_log /home/example/access.log;

    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /home/example/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
    root /home/example/evil_contact/public;
}
```

Now when accessing `http://sub.example.com` the access.log and error.log file do not have any entry. It is as if the request wouldn't arrive over at nginx or does not get passed through.

Let me know if there is something else needed.
Maybe we are just missing something obvious here.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alrighty,

After dozen of coffees the solution was not to change the nginx settings, but check the DNS records.

Afterall, the DNS entry had still a wrong IP assigned, so the request was going somewhere else.